# Swift 3.2 - app background displays black before displaying chosen image

Tags: swift, macos, background

I have set a specific picture to serve as background for my app.
During launch of the app (after archiving it), a light grey background appears very briefly before displaying the background picture I chosen. I would like to get rid of this, but how?

Here is the code I am using to change the background picture of the app :

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification){
    self.window.backgroundColor = NSColor(patternImage: imagedeFond!)
    self.window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
    self.window.isMovableByWindowBackground = true
}
```

The picture format is png.
Thanks

Comment: Is it possibly just the launch screen?

Comment: Yes, it is the launch screen.

Comment: I made a mistake in the title of the question. It is grey, not black. Sorry.

Comment: Other apps don't have this problem, so I guess there is something to do to avoid this.

Comment: I tested background image change when the app runs (attach to an action) and then the grey background does not appears, the new image shows up immediately. I guess some initialization settings have to be changed. I tried to switch on "Unified Title and Toolbar" but it refuses to switch on. Idem for "Full Size Content View" and "Close, Minimize, Resize".

Comment: Do it with applicationWillFinishLaunching instead.

Comment: Thank you El Tomato, it is working. I replaced all the content which was inside "func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification){}" inside func applicationWillFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification){}